# Does an unconditionally convergent series of complex numbers converge absolutely?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, complex-numbers, absolute-convergence

Suppose $\sum a_n$ is a series of complex numbers, if $\sum a_n$ and its every rearrangement all converge to the same sum, does $\sum a_n$ converge absolutely?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, since $\mathbb{C}$ has finite dimension. You may find [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1912711/rearrangement-of-series-in-banach-space-and-absolute-convergence/1912717) helpful; quoting from the answer:

> **Theorem.** (*Dvoretsky-Rogers, 1950*) Every [unconditionally convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unconditional_convergence) series in a Banach space $X$ is absolutely convergent if and only if $X$ is finite dimensional.

---

To be clear: the above theorem is good to know, but overkill in your case: you want only the "easy" direction of this theorem. Here it goes:

1. Since $\sum_n a_n$ converges unconditionally, then so do $\sum_n \operatorname{Re}(a_n)$ and $\sum_n \operatorname{Im}(a_n)$.
2. These two are real-valued series, so by the result on $\mathbb{R}$ (which is given by (the contrapositive of) [Riemann's rearrangement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem)) $\sum_n \operatorname{Re}(a_n)$ and $\sum_n \operatorname{Im}(a_n)$ are both *absolutely* convergent.
3. Now, by the triangle inequality this immediately implies that $\sum_n a_n$ is absoltuely convergent as well: indeed, $$\sum_n \lvert a_n\rvert \leq \sum_n \lvert \operatorname{Re}(a_n)\rvert+\sum_n \lvert \operatorname{Im}(a_n)\rvert < \infty$$

Comment: Is there an elementary proof for $\mathbb C$ ?

Comment: Yes, I reckon. (1) If $\sum_n a_n$ converges unconditionally, then so do $\sum_n \operatorname{Re}(a_n)$ and $\sum_n \operatorname{Im}(a_n)$; (2) by the result on real-valued series, then $\sum_n \operatorname{Re}(a_n)$ and $\sum_n \operatorname{Im}(a_n)$ converge *absolutely*; (3) by the triangle inequality, this implies $\sum_na_n$ converges absolutely as well. @LeGrandDODOM

Comment: Thank you, and what's the gist of the proof for $\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: To be clear: the "hard" direction in the theorem above is to prove the converse (which the OP didn't ask about, but that I figured you be nice for them to know): if every unconditionally convergent series is convergent, then the space has finite dimension. The other direction is easy.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Erm. That where the word "easy" in my comments above is misleading. AFAIK, the base case for $\mathbb{R}$ is (the contrapositive of) [Riemann's rearrangement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem). So... "easy" assuming that one.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Edited my answer to give the "easy" proof of the "easy" direction.

Comment: Thanks for the details. You don't need Riemann's theorem in its entirety. Going for a proof by contradiction, all you need is a rearrangement that diverges to $\infty$ (which is quite easy to construct).