# If $(x_i)_i$ and $(\left\|x_i\right\|)_i$ are summable, are we able to show $\left\|\sum_ix_i\right\|\le\sum_i\left\|x_i\right\|$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis

Let

- $E$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space
- $I$ be a nonempty set
- $(x_i)_{i\in I}\subseteq E$ be *summable*$^1$

> If $E=\mathbb R$, we're able to show that $(\left\|x_i\right\|_E)_{i\in I}$ is summable too and $$\left\|\sum_{i\in I}x_i\right\|_E\le\sum_{i\in I}\left\|x_i\right\|_E\;.\tag1$$ However, the proof of this claim that I know cannot be generalized to the case of an arbitrary normed $\mathbb R$-vector space $E$. So, my question are:
>
> 1. Are we able to generalize the described result?
> 2. If not, are we able to show $(1)$ under the additional assumption that $(\left\|x_i\right\|_E)_{i\in I}$ is summable?

$^1$ i.e. $\exists x\in E$ with $$\forall\varepsilon>0:\exists J\subseteq I:|J|\in\mathbb N\Rightarrow\forall K\subseteq I:|K|\in\mathbb N\text{ and }J\subseteq K\Rightarrow\left\|x-\sum_{k\in K}x_k\right\|_E<\varepsilon$$ and $$\sum_{i\in I}x_i:=x\;.$$

Comment: For 1, no. Google "Dvoretzky Rogers Theorem".

Comment: Building on @DavidMitra's comment: see also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1912711/rearrangement-of-series-in-banach-space-and-absolute-convergence/1912717) (includes a statement of the said theorem).